# initiate parent method from child view SWIFT

Tags: function, methods, swift, parent

I'm looking for the best possible way to initiate a parent method from a child's view controller.

The parent is a scroll view with three UIViewController children nested inside. The code to have them initialized and attached works fine... just can't seem the find a way to call methods of parent.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Just some terminology clarification. You "call" a method, you don't "initiate" it. You "initialize" a type to create a new instances of that type. Also, views can have "subviews" and "superviews" but are not generally referred to as children. View Controllers can have child view controllers and parent view controllers. The only relationship between views and view controllers is that view controllers each have a view. The view knows nothing about it's view controller. So, just because one view contains other views, doesn't mean there is any relationship between the view controllers.

Comment: okay I see what you are saying. So is it possible for a view to call the method of it's superview still even though the subview doesn't know it's view controller?

Comment: Every view has a reference to its superview through it's `superview` property so it can call methods on its superview.

Comment: so to call a super view method would this be a valid statement.. let x = self.view.superview!; x()//Method name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic way to call (public/internal) methods in a parent from a child or another class entirely is to save a reference to the parent in the child

```
class parent { 
    ...

    internal func doSomething() { 
        println("Did something...")
    }
}

class child {
    let pReference: parent

    init(p: parent) {
        self.pReference = p
    }

    internal func callInParent() {
        self.pReference.doSomething()
    }
}

let x = parent()
let y = child(x)
y.callInParent() // prints "Did something..."
```

This is easy to practise inside a playground. Give it a go.

Comment: everything checks out fine. I was finally able to initialize all my views without much trouble. I just worked out the problem, I notice your code had a syntax error (maybe you did that on purpose to test me! hahah) and I replaced p.doSomething() with pReference.doSomething() and what do you know, everything works perfect. Honestly I spent so much sleep trying to figure this out. your a real life saver! thanks a bunch for helping me!

Comment: Although I'm curious, this is the first time I've seen "internal" func... what is it?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that syntax error.

The "internal" part is an access modifier, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html